# Как создать трапецию на Geometry Nodes в Blender

Tags: 3d, blender

Как сделать трапецию с определённой толщиной стенок (типа solidify) исключительно на Geometry Nodes? Пример на картинках

[image: Пример 1]

[image: Пример 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, например, можно так, из цилиндра:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отлично, спасибо